# Maven import dependency Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: maven, kotlin, maven-3, kotlin-exposed

On the github page of Jetbrains' Exposed,a Kotlin SQL Framework, there is a link to a page where you can get the maven dependency for this library (https://bintray.com/kotlin/exposed/exposed/view#). The same dependecy can also be found on MVNRepository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.exposed/exposed/0.7.6).

I am using maven 3.3.9 and Intellij 2016.3.4, but maven cannot resolve this dependency. I check the ~/.m2/ directory and it seems that it is downloaded (there is a jar present). After looking at the repository I saw that there was no pom.xml and they where using Gradle.

Is it still possible to import this dependency with maven?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is listed on mvnrepository, but artifact itself is located in [Kotlin Exposed](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/kotlin-exposed) repository. You have to add link to the Exposed repository to your POM for Maven to find it.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>exposed</id>
        <name>exposed</name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: If using Nexus https://bintray.com/package/buildSettings?pkgPath=%2Fkotlin%2Fexposed%2Fexposed